# Bellman Ford algorithm relaxation

Tags: algorithms

In the Bellman-Ford algorithm's relaxation part, I can't seem to understand why we need to use (d[v] = min{ d[v], d[u] + c(u, v) }), the (c(u,v)) part. This uses the original weight. Why can't it use the least cost(shortest) between (u,v) instead of c(u,v)?

Comment: How do you know the length of the shortest path between $u$ and $v$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because the length of the shortest path between $u$ and $v$ is not known.  The purpose of the Bellman-Ford algorithm is to compute such lengths, so you can't assume they are already known.